# Node.js prompt-sync repeats prompt when using newline characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, newline, prompt

I'm working on a JavaScript assignment that requires me to use [prompt-synch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) in Node.JS. It works fine until I try to use a newline character `\n` within the prompt, at which point every character or backspace typed causes the prompt to repeat itself.

What could I do to get the user input to appear on a new line (a requirement of this exercise) without this issue?

Problem code:

```
if (guess < answer) {
  guess = prompt("Too low!\n> ");
} else if (guess > answer) {
  guess = prompt("Too high!\n> ");
}
```

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WEJT.png)

Comment: I get the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this instead.

```
if (guess < answer) {
  console.log("Too low!");
  guess = prompt("> ");
} else if (guess > answer) {
  console.log("Too high!");
  guess = prompt("> ");
}
```

If this does not work then it is likely an issue with another part of your own code. If it does, then it is likely an issue with the `prompt-sync` module, which makes this a valid workaround if you believe it is.

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't think of this ages ago. Thank you!