# Line wrapping issue in Terminal with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I'm working on a simple js exercise and running my file with Node, using the prompt-sync package to accept user input. When the user input becomes too long for the terminal window, it repeats the line back for every additional character typed (instead of wrapping the line normally), resulting in a large wall of text:

[screenshot of text-wall in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2vPK.png)

After multiple searches, I've yet to figure out why this is happening, although I've had a similar issue with prompt-sync in the past. Is there a way to prevent this repeating-line behaviour or work around it?

Comment: Was searching for this exact thing today, looks like that was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770848/node-js-prompt-sync-repeats-prompt-when-using-newline-characters

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why I reposted the same question three months apart...